# How to store versioned XSLT files in a microservice

Tags: python, xml, xslt, openshift

Currently I am developing a microservice to handle the transformation of XMLs (and other formats, but these don't matter at the moment). For the XML to XML transformation I use an XSLT file that describes the transformation. This XSLT has references to other XSLT files and it could be that there will be a new version in a year from now. Now the microservice is running inside a docker container that is served using kubernetes. The XSLT is now embedded in the repo and thus in the docker container, but if I want to change something I have to rebuild and redeploy the service. To fix this I have found multiple solutions, but each with their own drawbacks:

1. Keep it as it is now

   - (-) Hard to extend with new XSLTs or versions
   - (+) Easy to implement
2. Store the XSLT in a database

   - (-) Hard to reference other XSLTs effeciently
   - (+) Easy to update an XSLT or add a new one
   - (+) Decoupled from main code repo
3. Link the pod to a persistent volume

   - (-) Needs a system to handle uploading new XSLTs
   - (+) Can be used to version XSLT
   - (+) Decoupled from main code repo

What would be the best solution given the requirement that new XSLTs will be added and old ones have to be able to be updated and that deployment should be as easy and smooth as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more options to consider:

- Create a [`configMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) from the XSLT file, mount it as a volume so that the XSLT will become a file inside the container. There is a limit of ~1MB size (imposed by etcd) but it is unlikely for the XSLT file to be that big.
- Store the XSLT file in a code repo like git, file repository like nexus, or a plain web server, and use [init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) container to get the file from the repo and put it on a volume shared between the init container and the application container. [This example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container) could be a good starting point.

Comment: I like the second idea, it solves the con from the third option in the main post quite nicely. Everytime the main transformation service restarts it could run an init container to gather all XSLT files from a location and drop them in a folder in the persistent volume. Would it be possible to drop them inside the other container without a persistent volume? I guess not and a persistent volume is needed.

Comment: No, persistent volume isn't needed for this to work. See in the example linked from the answer - it uses a volume of type `emptyDir` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)